# Unable to Create a new emulator in eclispe

Tags: android, eclipse

I am unable to create a new emulator in the eclipse.I tried to run the  "**Android SDK Manager**" in console the error

**ERROR LOG:**

```
[2014-07-07 17:20:20 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] '"E:\SOFTWA~1\ADT-BU~1\sdk\tools\lib\\find_java.exe" -s' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
[2014-07-07 17:20:20 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] operable program or batch file.
[2014-07-07 17:20:20 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] '"E:\SOFTWA~1\ADT-BU~1\sdk\tools\lib\\find_java.exe" -s -w' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
[2014-07-07 17:20:20 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] operable program or batch file.
[2014-07-07 17:20:20 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] '""C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin\java.exe"" -jar lib\archquery.jar' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
[2014-07-07 17:20:20 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] operable program or batch file.
[2014-07-07 17:20:20 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] Invalid path
```

I tried to create a new emulator in eclipse but "**OK**" button is not visible.The image is[image: Emulator]

Can someone please help me

Comment: It is not an exact solution to your problem at all, but I would like to recommend `GenyMotion` as an alternative emulator, because it's really quick and works right.

Answer (score 2):

Please have look at label  CPU/ABI and it clearly showing that you have not installed any System Image for targeting API. download system image for that targeted API from sdk manager

Comment: Hi @Yograj Shinde how install the  CPU/ABI ?

Comment: @Ramesh Open SDK Manager from Eclipse and download system image for that targeted API from sdk manager

Answer (score 0):

You have not downloaded any image file
you should download it from SDK manager
`Window > Android SDK Manager`

Under Android 4.4W (API 20)
select Android Wear Intel x86......
and download it
after that restart eclipse and create new Device and select the Image Downloaded
Now you can create

Comment: Yes I have click the "Android SDK Manager" it not open any of  windows/popup

Comment: your computer might be slow,
if still doesn't resolve then go to the folder of your sdk
`adt-bundle-windows-xxx_xx-xxxxxxxx`
you will see SDK Manager there
thats the same Android SDK Manager